# Discord.PY I want to make an invite command

Tags: python, command, discord, discord.py

I want an invite command which someone could use (!invite) that would have the bot create an invite link.
So !invite 10 10 would make an invite available for 10 days with 10 uses. I'd rather have one that just puts it in the context channel's chat but one where it sends to a user as a dm is fine too.

Comment: What have you tried? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65674982/edit) your question and add what have you tried so far, where you're stuck, any errors/tracebacks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
async def createInvites(ctx, time_in_seconds,uses):
    invitelink = await discord.abc.GuildChannel.create_invite(ctx.message.channel, max_uses=uses,max_age=time_in_seconds)
    await ctx.send(invitelink)
```

This should work. First you type in the time in seconds, then the uses. Sadly Discord doesn't allow times over a day somehow or I missed something, but it should bring you closer to your goal at least.

Comment: Thanks. It’s better than what I was hoping to get so that’s good :D